# eslint@6.8.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "11.6.0"

Tags: react-native, eslint, react-native-cli

I tried to run `nix react-native init Hello` and get the following error:

```
error eslint@6.8.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "11.6.0"

error Found incompatible module.
```

I check that my node version is v13.11.0 but it say Got 11.6.0. Not sure where that version came from

Answer (score 0):

Well you're getting that error because your nodejs version isn't compatible. Simply go ahead to nodejs.org and download a recent version, install. That should do the magic for you!!!